# LINQ to SQL database row not updating

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database, linq

I am using LINQ to SQL to interact with my database and I am trying to do the following to update a single row in the database:

```
DataClassesDataContext dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();

TableName aRow = (from rows in dataContext.TableNames where rows.x == y select rows).Single();
aRow.attribute = "something";

dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

shouldn't this update the database with the change I made to the row?
or is there something I'm missing?

thanks for any help

Comment: Are you running inside a TransactionScope, by chance? If so, remember to [Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx) it. If not, ignore this comment.

Comment: Tangential, but: definitely consider replacing that first line by wrapping the code in a [using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that declares the data context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. Is your code snippet using the same `DataContext`, meaning it's not cut and pasted from different methods where you're instantiating new `DataContext` instances?
2. Is your `DataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled` property set to `true`?  It should be by default, but if it's `false` then your `DataContext` won't be able to perform the update.

Comment: in #2 wouldn't calling [SubmitChanges raise an Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled(v=VS.90).aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to check: ensure the table has a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work correctly, so it must be elsewhere in the code or in the database itself.

Have you checked to make sure that the column you are updating is not read-only?
As pst mentioned, are you using transactions?