# Linq to sql not updating properly

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to update records with linq to sql. The code does not throw any errors, but the changes are not getting to the database. I don't know how to debug this problem. Object tracking is enabled for the datacontext, as suggested here [LINQ to SQL database row not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390808/linq-to-sql-database-row-not-updating)

I am confident that my datacontext is pointing to the correct database.

```
        Dim myAverageWeeklyLab As AverageWeeklyLab = (From l In myAlexanderValidation.AverageWeeklyLabs Where l.labname = lab).First
        myAverageWeeklyLab.GracePeriod = standardDeviation  
        myAlexanderValidation.SubmitChanges()  //this should set the gracePeriod field=standardDeviation, but does not
```

What am I missing? What steps can I take to debug this problem?

Comment: have you double checked the value of the item? Debug up to the SubmitChanges line and check. Also, are you entirely sure that the changes aren't being made? Maybe they are and you are looking at an data context item that has not been refreshed yet following changes to the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your table as a primary key.

Comment: That did it. The table had no PK, so would not update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.First` to `.First()`

Make sure `myAlexanderValidation` is a `DataContext`

Place a semicolon at the end of each line